# Javascript me lanza undefined

Tags: javascript, html

¿Hice algo mal con mi javascript? Cuando le doy click al boton que es una imagen me aparece undefined y no sé que hice mal.

Quiero que cada vez que se haga click el botón me aparezca uno de esos números pero solo me aparece `undefined` y no se que esta mal y si es mi `javascript` o es mi `index`.

```js
var quotes = [
        "0",
        "17",
        "34",
        "51",
        "68",
        "85",
        "102",
        "119",
        "136",
        "153",
        "170",
        "187",
        "204",
        "221",
        "238",
        "255",
        "272",
        "289",
        ]
    
    function newQuote() {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = 
    quotes[randomNumber]}
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>MultiploAleatorioDe17</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="black" text="cyan"><h1></h1> 
    <center><table><tr><td></td>
    <img src="D:\Usuario\Desktop\a\configuracion.jpg" align="right">
    <div id="quoteDisplay">
    </div>
    <button onclick="newQuote()"><img 
    src="D:\Usuario\Desktop\a\generate.jpg"></button>
    <a href="index.html">
    <img src="D:\Usuario\Desktop\a\volver.jpg" align="left"></a></td> 
    </tr></table></center>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

No se porque cuando le doy click a la imagen me aparece eso

Comment: ¿Cómo luce tu html? Ponlo. Lo más probable es que no exista nada con id `quoteDisplay` y por eso el error. Coloca también el texto del error para determinar con certeza de qué se trata.

Comment: lo añadi ahora pueden ver si tiene un error porque yo creo que hise todo bien

Comment: gracias, eso hive antes de preguntar aqui y me di cuenta de que mi javascipt estaba en mi escritorio y no en la carpeta porque en la cosola me decia que ese archivo no cargaba pero cuando lo movi el boton solo me da undefinido pero me fui a elementos y le di click a la imagen y cuando hago eso me marca el div y cuando le doy click a el div en el inspeccionat me aparece en texto de undefinido asi que yo creo que el error debe estar ahi

Comment: ¿la del javascript? porque esa llave esta cerrada no se si hice un error escribiendo el javascript en mi comentario pero esta cerrado

Comment: ¿sabes como evitar eso de la imagen? quiero pasar en un pendrive la carpeta a mi profesor para que la vea para un trabajo pero cuando la paso por pendribe las imagenes aparecen sin cargar ¿sabes si hay una manera para prevenir eso?

Comment: gracias por cierto ejecute el sniped o como se llame y me aparecio esto
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: newQuote is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 34
}

Comment: Jolin, tienes poderes!!  A mi no me sale eso... me sale un numero cada vez que pulso la supuesta imagen del centro... y aunque le de muchas veces me sigue saliendo un numero... eso si que es raro raro raro... prueba con otro navegador, a ver si tendras un problema más serio de forma local

Comment: Por cierto, para que si viene alguien no se queje, borra tus comentarios que no esten aportando ya nada al problema... los comentarios son para pequeñas aclaraciones y no deben usarse como un chat, aunque a veces lo usemos así cuando algo no queda claro, pero luego lo limpiamos

Comment: listo y para mañana me hare un supereroe sere ERRORCODEman pero ya hablando encerio intente en 3 navegadore y todos me salen lo mismo ¿sera mi computadora? intente en goggle chrome opera GX y opera pero bueno estoy seguro que mi profesor de secundaria aprobara mi pagina mal codificada

Comment: pues no lo entiendo... yo he probado en dos navegadores y en ambos todo bien... bueno, suerte con tu profe, tu código está bien, eso no tengo dudas, lo otro que te sucede ni idea... virus? esperemos que no, je... venga, saludos!

Comment: saludos! gracias por la ayuda y que curioso que vi tu comentario hace 34 segundos bueno voy a intentar probar otras cosas haber si algo funciona nos vemos